# Phpmyadmin return query that ends after after current time and run it via php code

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem: I have a select statement that I can run on my site as following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_my_calendar AS cal, wp_my_calendar_categories AS cat
INNER JOIN cal ON cal.event_category = cat.category_id
WHERE cal.event_category = cat.category_Id 
  AND event_end > NOW()
ORDER BY event_category, event_begin
```

When I execute this on my site it gives me all records from the category's even events that are from 2016! instead of just the ones that end after the current date event_end is of type date

Sorry for this question but I am quite new to SQL and I am working with a mess of a database (not mine). any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not mix old join syntax (comma) with the newer INNER JOIN syntax

Comment: You are filtering on event_end field only. Perhaps the event started in 2016. Point is: without seeing the underlying data, it is very difficult to guess what may have gone wrong.